# Underscore template <script type="text/template></script> within another template

Tags: javascript, templates, backbone.js

I'm using underscore + express to render a web page, here's an example of a template:

```
<!doctype>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title><%= title %></title>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="description"><%= description %></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Everything good so far, however I'd like to use the following markup within the page:

```
<script type="text/template">
    <div class="foo"><%= bar %></div>
</script>
```

If I'll use it, then the server-side underscore will try to parse it and that's not my intention, I'd like to use _.template on the client side as well.

Is there any way I can ignore some parts of the template? I went through the docs, but I didn't find anything . Something like this would be really useful:

```
<%! %>
```

Example:

```
<%!
<script type="text/template">
    <%= text %>
</script>
%>
```

I know I can compile the page in parts, but is there a better solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set your client-side template settings to use different interpolation settings so they don't conflict with the server side ones. See http://underscorejs.org/#template

```
_.templateSettings = {
  interpolate: /<%!(.+?)%>/g
};
```

Note you might have to escape some of the characters.

Comment: True, but I'd rather use erb than {{.

Comment: Your question mentioned using `<%! %>` which is exactly what you can do by defining your own interpolation. See updated answer.

Comment: You should probably provide new `evaluate` and `escape` regexes too.

Comment: <%! %> should be used to ignore certain parts of the template, I don't want to change the interpolation settings